# Eclipse not running my android app

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, android-emulator

When I want to run an app to emulator , eclipse give me this error :

> [2014-04-09 11:02:38 - ErsalNazar] Failed to create a Launch config for project 'ErsalNazar': Could not write file: E:\workspace.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.debug.core.launches.

too show this dialog box  sometimes 
[image]

I am sorry for bad Language .

Comment: remove your emulator and recrete it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new workspace and copy your project in this new workspace

Comment: i hate eclipse "does not work ?" "Ooooh, we know that issue, just re-set your whole workspace and it might work"

Answer (score 1):

This can happen when:

1. You have multiple copies of the Android SDK installed on your
   machine. You're updating the available images and devices for one
   SDK, and trying to debug or run your app in another. If using
   Eclipse, take a look at your "Preferences | Android | SDK Location".
   Make sure it's the path you expect. If not, change the path to point
   to where you think the Android SDK is installed.
2. You don't have an Android device setup in your emulator. For solve this issue check http://techtraveller.blogspot.in/2009/07/android-fixed-unknown-virtual-device.html